# List of Oracle views using specific table name

Tags: oracle, view, find, names

I wish to find a list of all views under specific schema using mentioned table name.

e.g. if view1 and view2 uses table1, using table name "table1", I wish to find view names "view1" and view2".

Please let me know, how can I do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_dependencies 
WHERE TYPE = 'VIEW'
    AND referenced_type = 'TABLE'
```

Comment: Perfect :) Adding more info to your answer, to find views referencing to my specific table I added nother condition to check "referenced_name". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bear in mind you may want to just view the OWNER you are interested in, or at least exclude SYS. `AND owner = 'MYSCHEMA'`.

Answer (score 12):

```
select 
    * 
from 
    all_dependencies
where 
    type='VIEW'
    and referenced_name like '%table_name%'
    and referenced_type = 'TABLE'
```